# how to group multiple rows count number with its container

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two table called eventsn  and events
On the eventsn table i have:  eventsname, eventsID, userID
And on eventstable I have:  content, userID  and eventsID
I want to count the number of posted event by the user  and group it by eventsname

Note on my site i have my own default events that was already been stored in eventsn table.
I have to count from both default events and users created events

Now look at my table

Eventsn table structure

```
eventsID, eventsname, userID.           
1,        EventA,     admin
2,        EventB,     admin
3,        praise,     0001
4,        EventC,     admin
```

Events table structure

```
eventsID, content, userID.           
1,        xxx,     0001
2,        xyy,     0001
2,        xxxq,    0001
2,        yyyy,    0001
```

My expected result will look like this

E.G
User A post:

```
Eventsname capacity

EventA:    1
EventB:    3
praise:    0
EventC:    0
```

This is  what I have  tried:

```
<?php
   public function rating() {
     $this -> jpt_connect();
     $userID= $this ->users_info('userID');
     $rating_ar = array();

     $sql =mysql_query("SELECT
       evn.eventsname,
       COUNT(ev.content) as  no
       FROM eventsn as evn
       LEFT JOIN  events   as ev 
       ON.  (evn.userID = '$userID')
       AND (evn.eventsID=ev.eventsID )
     WHERE evn.userID ='admin'
     OR  evn.userID='$userID' ")
   or   die(mysql_error());

   while($row= mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $rating_ar[] =$row;
   }

   return $rating_ar;
}

$j = new jkp();
$array =$j -> rating();
?>
```

I but nothing happen Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not too sure about my answer... what would be the expected otput for user 0001?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

```
SELECT eventsn.eventsname, eventsn.userid, COUNT(events.eventid) AS tot
FROM
  eventsn LEFT JOIN events
  ON eventsn.eventid = events.eventid
GROUP BY
  eventsn.eventsname, eventsn.userid
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/415805/1).